# combinatorics skeleton of a cube

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We are given a 12cm long wire and we need to create edge-skeleton of cube with edge length 1 cm
from it. We glue pieces of wires at the vertices of the cube. Into how many pieces do we
have to cut our wire minimum to be able to create the skeleton of the cube?

Comment: Please don't go back and edit your questions to remove their contents; other people may later have the same question you do, so we want to leave the question here for them to find.

Comment: One way (but not the only way) to add context to problem-statement-questions is to show your own approach.  Surely you can think of a way that uses fewer pieces of wire than there are edges on the cube?  I'd love to vote to reopen your Question, but you should make some effort to present the problem in a way that expresses your interest in learning some math from it.

Answer (score 5):

Each piece can be used to form a path along the vertices (corners) of the cube, but we know from basic graph theory that a path can have at most two veritices with an odd degree.

So, since you have $8$ vertices with an odd degree ($3$), you'll need to cut it in at least $4$ pieces.

And, it is easy to verify that we can indeed do it with $4$ pieces: 
[image]

Comment: @JackDaurizio Thank you for adding the visual! :) I had wanted to create one where each of the  $4$ pieces would go in each of the three directions, but this is very nice too.